# Can we use the notation $\lim$ without knowing the existence of the limit?

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

According to the 3rd entry of https://www.jirka.org/spivak-errata.html, we cannot take the limit of before we know it exists. Does this mean that arguments like
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}g(x)=\alpha$$
or
$$0\leq\lim_{x\rightarrow a}|f(x)-\alpha|\leq\lim_{x\rightarrow a}|g(x)-\alpha|=0$$
given $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow a}g(x)=\alpha$, are really invalid? I have seen some textbooks using these kinds of arguments. For example, Moskowitz & Paliogiannis' *Functions of Several Real Variables* and Chung's *Elementary probability theory*.

Comment: Once you have proved that the composition of continuous functions is continuous, you know expressions like these are well defined. Can you see why?

Answer (score 1):

*Strictly speaking these arguments are indeed invalid. They can however easily be turned into a completely rigorous argument. For example in your second point the rigorous way to formulate the proof would be:*

Let $f$ and $g$ be real functions so that $\lim_{x \to a} g(x) = \alpha$. Assume $\lvert f(x) - \alpha \rvert \leq \lvert g(x) - \alpha \rvert$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$. Because $\lim_{x \to a} 0 = 0 = \lim_{x \to a} g(x)$ we can now apply the squeeze theorem to find that $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = \lim_{x \to a} g(x) = \alpha$.

*Authors like the ones you mention might indeed omit this full proof but it is always implied. This can however be confusing if it is your first analysis class.*